# Copy a table row from one table to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to copy a row from one table to the other using jQuery when a checkbox in that row is checked.

I tried using the `.clone()` method but this had very strange behaviour. Even though the jQuery was specifically targeting rows in the second table, when copied to the first, it could still be targeted. So either clone() is not right or I need to use something else.

```
$('#offers tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').click(function (e) {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

Comment: What could still be targeted by what?

Comment: @Jon When the row from the second table was cloned, and the clone appended to the first table, it could still be targeted by the jQuery selector shown above

Comment: If suppose I want to add one drop down in table column additionally is it possible. Because I have doubt on this. I have table 1 need to take one row and put table 2 and add one drop down in the column is is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#offers tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').on('change', function (e) {
     var row = $(this).closest('tr').html();
     $('#otherTable tbody').append('<tr>'+row+'</tr>');
});
```

See it in action! http://jsfiddle.net/3BZp4/1/

Clone also SHOULD work for you and not effect future selection:

http://jsfiddle.net/AkVTw/1/

Now with catch for unchecking as per comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/wGGDb/

Comment: Your example doesn't work. When you uncheck it, it still copies to the other table

Comment: you never specified that was the desired behavior. please describe what you would like to occur in greater detail. Should 'unchecking' remove it from the second list? What is your goal here?

Comment: `when a checkbox in that row is checked.` Pretty sure that means that when it's unchecked, it shouldn't copy that row.

Comment: `when its unchecked it shouldn't copy that row`? It doesn't copy it if you had not checked it. Are you looking for it UN-COPY if you UN-CHECK the box? What is your goal here? Please be more specific.

Comment: In your example. If you check a box in the first table, it copies to the second table. (Desired). If you uncheck the same box, it copies to the second table again.