# How to copy specific content from one table to another using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I am currently developing a tool to display large amount of data in different tables. Different amount of data from one table has to be assigned into another table more than once. This view takes almost 20 seconds to load and i want to lower the time by manipulating the DOM instead of assigning every match within PHP. I want to place a few identifiers hidden in the first table and on click of one row, show the additional data within the next  element.

Here is an example how the Tables look before:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="iWantToClickThis">
        <td>Bla Bla</td>
        <td style="visibility:hidden;">3,5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table style="visibility:hidden">
    <tr>
        <th>Additional Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
        <td>Additional Info 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td>Additional Info 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3=>
        <td>Additional Info 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
        <td>Additional Info 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="5">
        <td>Additional Info 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="6">
        <td>Additional Info 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And after the click:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="iWantToClickThis">
        <td>Bla Bla</td>
        <td style="visibility:hidden;">3,4,5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Additional Header</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="3">
                    <td>Additional Info 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="5">
                    <td>Additional Info 5</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
</table>
```

I've found out how to achieve this with a single row but how do i do that with different, identitying them by their ids?

Comment: Do you mandatory need to reference to them by ID? Can you add them a class if they match a criteria and then use the class to move them?

Comment: May be this link will help you 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757047/copy-a-table-row-from-one-table-to-another-using-jquery

Comment: The ID is the only relation between both. I could add the corresponding id from the other entry. There is a ManyToMany relation between the tables. The first table can have many rows with the same id from the second table.

Comment: Please describe what you _actually_ want to achieve here (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)). It rather sounds like you want to dynamically show or not show complete “columns” of an existing set of data – in that case you should not create multiple tables, but use one table, and simply hide the unwanted columns. Best (cross-browser) way to do this would be to give the TD elements a class corresponding to their column, and then hide them by adding a class to the table element itself, by providing CSS rules that make use of the child combinator.

Comment: The first table is a material list with, lets say, 500 positions. The second is a job list with maybe 20 jobs in it. On click on any of the positions, i want to show all the jobs the material is used in. It may be possible that every position in the list is used in at least one job. I don't want to copy the same job 500 times in a table beneath every position and then hide it with css because the user is mostly just looking for one or two positions. I want to hide the job list completely and only copy the needed jobs in a table beneath the position on click.